# "As indicated in the attachment" replacement

Tags: email, informal-writing

When you're writing an email, how to emphasize that the reader should find the evidence in the attached files.
Is "As indicated in the attachment" correct?

Comment: "As indicated in the attachment" isn't a complete sentence. It may or may not be appropriate depending on context.

Comment: It is more direct to say "Please see the attached resume for details."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would work fine if you put it in parentheses in the appropriate place in a sentence.  If you want a stand-alone sentence, one option is

> Please see attached.

Or

> Please see attached evidence [or: documentation].

But when I am sending a bunch of attachments as part of some petition, and there's a lot of stuff for the reader to go through, I try to make the attachment reading and the connecting of the dots easier for the reader.  For example, I might give them a list (in the body of the email) of the names of the attachments.  I might number each attachment so they can follow along, reading the attachments in order as they are reading my petition.  I might make a zip file of each group of attachments, and give each zip file a self-documenting name.  I might put the name of the relevant document or zip file in parentheses at the end of each section (or at the beginning, e.g. "See department-level-appeal.zip").

Of course, if it's a legal matter, then the answer would be quite different, and you'd do best to ask at Law.SE.

Comment: I'm really appreciate you making the time to put a detailed answer.